# Java Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java

Following code

```
BigInteger number=new BigInteger("2154789654785210095153123254756845");
boolean b=number.longValue()>Long.MIN_VALUE;
boolean c=number.longValue()<Long.MAX_VALUE;
boolean d=number.longValue()>=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
boolean e=number.longValue()<=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(""+b);
System.out.println(""+c);
System.out.println(""+d);
System.out.println(""+e);
```

generates output

```
true
true
false
true
```

Keeping in mind that after achieving `MAX_VALUE` in Integer,value goes back to `MIN_VALUE` and loops again, if a value is `<=Integer.MAX_VALUE`, then it must be `>=Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then why does boolean variable `d` returns `false`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be explained once we understand what [`longValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue--) is returning.

> Converts this BigInteger to a long. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

Printing the value of this variable yields `-4694333933485660691`, a value that is certainly a legal `long` value but is far less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (which is implicitly converted to a `long` here), so `false` is correct for the `d` printout.

Both the `b` and `c` outputs are `true` because the value `-4694333933485660691` is greater than `Long.MIN_VALUE`, and because the value `-4694333933485660691` is less than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  The only values that would print `false` for `b` and `c` are those `BigInteger`s that would convert to `Long.MIN_VALUE` AND `Long.MAX_VALUE` themselves, respectively, when `longValue()` is called.

Comment: Might want to point out that with `long >= int`, the `int` value is coerced to `long` before the compare.

Comment: @MaxZoom why wouldn't they be?

Comment: The only way b could be false would be if the longValue were *exactly* MIN_VALUE, all other longs are greater.  Similar with c.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily understood by printing values as below

```
number.longValue()[-4694333933485660691]>Long.MIN_VALUE[-9223372036854775808  =  true
number.longValue()[-4694333933485660691]<Long.MAX_VALUE[9223372036854775807  =  true
number.longValue()[-4694333933485660691]>=Integer.MIN_VALUE[-9223372036854775808  =  false
number.longValue()[-4694333933485660691]<=Integer.MAX_VALUE[9223372036854775807  =  true
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.8 you can use [`BigInteger.longValueExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValueExact--) which will throw an `ArithmeticException` if the BigInteger value cannot be exactly expressed as long value.